# Prove $\sin(\theta )+\sin(\theta -\phi )=2\cos(\frac{\phi }{2})\sin(\theta -\frac{\phi }{2})$

Tags: trigonometry

This function was pieced together from graphing by observing rate of change of amplitude and phase, but I would like a more rigorous proof:

$\sin(\theta )+\sin(\theta -\phi )=2\cos(\frac{\phi }{2})\sin(\theta -\frac{\phi }{2})$

Comment: Have you tried applying the angle-addition formulas?

Comment: I have, and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sin(A-B) = \sin A \cos B - \sin B\cos A$ and $\sin(A+B) = \sin A \cos B + \sin B \cos A$ so adding the two gives $$2\sin A \cos B = \sin(A-B) + \sin (A+B).$$

Now choose suitable values for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I think the second formula is $\sin B\cos A$

Comment: @David Oops yes, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\sin A+\sin B =2.\sin(\frac{A+B}{2}).\cos(\frac{A-B}{2})$$

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee and what exactly is my error?

Comment: I have just supplied the formal name of the formula.

Comment: why the dots? just curious.

Comment: @TheCount Multiplication. Sign

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't see that convention often, so I wanted to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No a proof but a confirmation of the conjecture:

- for $\theta=0$, $\sin(0)+\sin(-\phi )=2\cos(\frac{\phi }{2})\sin(-\frac{\phi }{2})$,
- for $\phi=0$, $\sin(\theta )+\sin(\theta )=2\cos(0)\sin(\theta)$,
- for $\theta=\phi$, $\sin(\theta )+\sin(0)=2\cos(\frac{\phi }{2})\sin(\frac{\phi }{2})$.